# How does 'all' work in "Are these two agreements all right?"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

The title of an earlier question is:

> Are these two agreements all right?

I'm not sure whether that title means (1) or (2) below.

1. "Are both these two agreements right?"
2. "Are these two agreements entirely right?"

Stated otherwise, how does "all" work in that title?

Answer (score 12):

A native speaker who only just specified that there are exactly two agreements wouldn't use "all" to refer to them; he'd use "both". I.e.

> Are these two agreements both right?

Or simply,

> Are both these agreements right?

And even then, I'm not sure he'd use the word *right* in this case. Perhaps *correct*, or *valid*, or *complete*, or *legal*, or whatever suits the context — the point is, *right* is unlikely to be used because it would raise the question, right *about what*?

So for these reasons, "all right" quite obviously functions as a single unit here, meaning "fine, acceptable, adequate, satisfactory". There is no ambiguity.

But what if there were more than two agreements? Well, let's see:

> Are these agreements all right?

This actually could be construed to be ambiguous; it *could* mean "are these agreements okay", and it *could* mean "are all of these agreements right". But again, in the latter case you'd probably use a different adjective and/or move the "all" to the front (like I just did). So syntactically both interpretations would make sense, but semantically the second one would still be more likely.

Comment: Reg, even if you still have that strange "R", I'm glad to hear from you. Stay with us, we need of competent speakers here. Thank you.

Comment: @Carlo_R. It is not a R: It is the [Cyrillic Ya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ya_\(Cyrillic\)). `;)`

Comment: @kiam, every day one learns the most unexpected things. Thank you.

Comment: That's true, though in English it's often used as a *faux Cyrillic* R to give a Russian flavor to something, as in *TETЯIS: The Soviet Mind Game*.   (That would be Тетрис in actual Cyrillic.)  A similar glyph appears in *Toys "Я" Us*, in which it represents R written backwards, as by a child.

Answer (score 2):

*All right* in that case means "acceptable."

> Is the coffee all right?

As in other cases, *all right* is synonym with *OK*.

> I hope the children are all right.

> Do you feel all right?

> Are you sure it's all right for me to leave early?

Comment: kiam, yes, but is it correct to use "all right" in reference to grammar facts?

Comment: As _all right_ means _acceptable_, yes it is all right.

Answer (score 1):

If the question asks whether the two agreements are correct, then what the writer needs to say is *Are these two agreements both right?*  *Are these two agreements all right?* asks if they are acceptable. In such cases, the spelling *alright* can remove any ambiguity.